# Is there a way to copy text in git bash (on Windows) using just the keyboard?

Tags: bash, git, text, editor, git-bash

I want to copy text, either -

- the output of the previous command, OR
- any text present in the bash window,

simply by navigating the cursor and selecting the text using only the keyboard. I do not want to use the mouse at all.

1. Is there any way to do this?
2. If impossible, is there any way to do this with minimal use of the mouse?

**Example use case** - copying the name of a branch, or a commit ID (from a previous `git log` or `git branch`) and then pasting it in a git command for switching to it.

Comment: On git-bash window bar, right click, Options, Mouse, check `copy on select` and select `Paste` for right mouse button. Select to copy and right click to paste, which I find quite convenient.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because you are stick to the command line prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the shortcut by

with keys: `> options > keys > shortcuts`

or

with mouse `> options > mouse > mouse functions`

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked is for:

- desktop keyboard: [shift] + [insert] keys to paste
- laptop keyboard: [shift] + [0] keys to paste

NB: For laptops, the 0 Key at the bottom of the number pad on the upper-right corner of your keyboard will function as an Insert Key when Num Lock is turned off. That is why it is labeled with both 0 and Ins on the key itself.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1639562/how-to-customize-shortcut-keys-on-git-bash-terminal-windows-10) on another forum. One just has to enable to Ctrl + Shift + Letter keys from the bash terminal's options. One can then use Ctrl + Shift + C to copy and Ctrl + Shift + V to paste.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy but can't paste text or number on Windows.

Just copy with shortcut ctrl + v. After copying, press right mouse click to paste wherever you want.

Paste will reset when press left mouse button.